# Elements not extending parent element height

Tags: css, html, containers, parent-child

I have a container in which I'm putting a bunch of elements, and my expectation was that the container would expand downward as the container filled with elements. Unfortunately, this is not the case. I have some div's that are floating over the edge of my container. I was able to remedy this with a bunch of break tags, but this was a sloppy solution.

Perhaps my CSS is incorrect, but I can't figure out where. The long select list and the major description **should** reside in the upper, white box.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T2fG2/).

EDIT: Uwe led me to research floats. I've discovered that floats are not considered in the normal flow layout. So how is this fixable?

EDIT 2: I found a clearfix solution.

```
.clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}
* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
} /* Hides from IE-mac \*/
    .clearfix {
        display: block;
}
```

Comment: What I would guess is that the `float` CSS attribute is the cause for this (although I'm no expert on these things).

Comment: I've stumbled across a clearfix solution. See my edited post.

Comment: @Jon: another clearfix solution (shorter): http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/

Comment: Thanks Geert. Could you briefly explain how clearfixes work? I'm not sure I understand them.

Comment: My preferred method for clearing floats is simply to add overflow:auto; to the containing element. Here is a jsfiddle with an overflow declaration applied to your .container element: http://jsfiddle.net/nzM77/2/ For more on this technique see: http://www.sitepoint.com/simple-clearing-of-floats/ Can require some tweaking for older versions of IE to trigger haslayout, such as specifying a width for the container element (it may only be IE6 that has issues, since I almost never run into problems using this technique these days).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to clear floats; simply appending `overflow: hidden;` to `.main` will solve your problem.

In practice though, it's probably better to directly clear the floats which are causing the problems rather than applying a fix to the parent div. I would actually recommend appending the following properties to .bottom instead:

```
.bottom {
    clear: both;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

- `clear: both` takes care of clearing the floats in `.content`.
- `overflow: hidden` takes care of clearing the floats in `.bottom`

You should also look into using the [`id`](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/core-attributes/id) attribute in addition to the `class` attribute for your HTML tags.